# How can i scroll top on onPress of button in react-native?

Tags: button, react-native, scroll, onpress

I have added the button in bottom of simple screen and I want to scroll top whenever I press the button. what code to add to button onPress?, Please suggest any solution, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a ScrollView on your page since you want to scroll to the top whenever a button is pressed at the bottom. In that case, you can use `scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})` method of `ScrollView`. You can call a function before the render method like this:

```
goToTop = () => {
   this.scroll.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
}
render() {
 return (
  <ScrollView
    ref={(c) => {this.scroll = c}}
  >
    // [rest of your code here...]
    <Button title='Go To Top' onPress={this.goToTop} />
  </ScrollView>
 )
}
```

Basically, you have to create a reference(`ref`) to your scrollView and then you can call its method anywhere in your code.

In case you are not using ScrollView, but instead, you are using the Flatlist component, it also has a method exposed via its `ref`s called scrollToOffset().

Comment: what can i do to scroll bottom?

Comment: @kalyani_jamunkar `this.scroll.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })`

Answer (score 2):

In React Native for functional component, need to do following things to work scroll Top in ScrollView-

1.Define globally in functional component :-
   const scroll = React.createRef();

2. then, do add :- ref={scroll} in ScrollView.

3.Finally, on click add :-
scroll.current.scrollTo(0); // will scroll to the top at y-position 0

Answer (score 0):

// const scroll = React.createRef();

if u get Error that scroll.current is Null then try this

const scroll = React.useRef();

This worked in my Case.